# TCL floating output of expr used with conditional operator '<' not working

Tags: tcl, expr

I am using TCL 8.4 While the following works as expected,

```
% if { 50.02 < 50.02 } { puts HI }
% set s 50.02
50.02
% if { $s <  50.02 } { puts HI }
% set high 50.02
50.02
% if { $s <  $high } { puts HI }
%
%
% if { 50.02 < $high } { puts HI }
```

Why this following does not work ? I really cannot understand this behavior. Note : when $s is 50.03, it works as expected.

```
% set s [ expr 50.01 + 0.01 ]
50.02
% if { $s <  $high } { puts HI }
HI
% set s [ expr double(50.01 + 0.01) ]
50.02
% if { $s <  $high } { puts HI }
HI
```

Comment: after doing this workaround: `set s [expr double(round(($s+ 0.01) * 100) / 100.0)]`,  it works

Comment: Oh, it's _this_ question again! Different guise, same old problem.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers cannot be stored precisely. For two numbers which mathematically are supposed to be equal, the comparison result may be incorrect.

My Tcl 8.6 prints (and that may explain the result you get):

```
% set s [ expr 50.01 + 0.01 ]
50.019999999999996
```

More details about this are available at [wiki.tcl.tk: A real problem](http://wiki.tcl.tk/879)